# Ad hoc 2x2 contingency tables SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, statistics

I'm looking at ways of creating [contingency tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_tables) in SQL Server 2008. They don't necessarily have to appear in the 2x2 typical matrix.  I'd just like to know if anyone out there can see a better solution than mine.

[image]
Please refer to the picture for clarity.  The red letters are names of the squares for simplicity's sake.  The label X+ means X is present in that cell and the opposite is true as well.

I will label my queries with the letter of box in the table that they represent

```
A

       select count(*) from 
    (

    select distinct p.patientid
        from Patient as p
        inner join icdpatient as picd on picd.patientid = p.patientid
        and picd.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
        and picd.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
        inner join tblicd as t on t.icd_id = picd.icd_id
        where t.icdText like '%x%' 
    ) as t
    inner join 
    (
    select distinct p.patientid
        from Patient as p
        inner join icdpatient as picd on picd.patientid = p.patientid
        and picd.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
        and picd.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
        inner join tblicd as t on t.icd_id = picd.icd_id
        where t.icdText like '%y%'
    ) as s on s.patientid=t.patientid
```

---

```
B
select count(*) from 
(

select distinct p.patientid
    from Patient as p
    inner join icdpatient as picd on picd.patientid = p.patientid
    and picd.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
    and picd.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
    inner join tblicd as t on t.icd_id = picd.icd_id
    where t.icdText like '%x%' 
) as t
left join 
(
select distinct p.patientid
    from Patient as p
    inner join icdpatient as picd on picd.patientid = p.patientid
    and picd.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
    and picd.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
    inner join tblicd as t on t.icd_id = picd.icd_id
    where t.icdText like '%y%'
) as s on s.patientid=t.patientid
where s.patientid is null
```

---

```
C
select * from 
(

select distinct p.patientid
    from Patient as p
    inner join icdpatient as picd on picd.patientid = p.patientid
    and picd.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
    and picd.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
    inner join tblicd as t on t.icd_id = picd.icd_id
    where t.icdText like '%x%' 
) as t
right join 
(
select distinct p.patientid
    from Patient as p
    inner join icdpatient as picd on picd.patientid = p.patientid
    and picd.admissiondate = p.admissiondate
    and picd.dischargedate = p.dischargedate
    inner join tblicd as t on t.icd_id = picd.icd_id
    where t.icdText like '%y%'
) as s on s.patientid=t.patientid
where t.patientid is null
```

D
This one I'm a little iffy about but I think I'm going to do something like

```
declare @d int
set @d = (select count(distinct p.patientid) from Patient as p) - b -c
```

This aims to find the entire population and subtracting those ONLY with X and ONLY with y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!  There are easier ways.  Assuming your join produces no duplicate patients:

```
select (case when t.icdText like '%x%' then 'X' else 'NO-X' end) as X,
       (case when t.icdText like '%y%' then 'Y' else 'NO-Y' end) as Y,
       count(*) as cnt
from Patient p inner join
     icdpatient picd
     on picd.patientid = p.patientid and
        picd.admissiondate = p.admissiondate and
        picd.dischargedate = p.dischargedate inner join
     tblicd t
     on t.icd_id = picd.icd_id
group by  (case when t.icdText like '%x%' then 'X' else 'NO-X' end),
           (case when t.icdText like '%y%' then 'Y' else 'NO-Y' end)
```

Otherwise replace the count(*) with:

```
count(distinct patientid)
```

This should give you the information you need for the contingency table.

Comment: need the alias after `tblicd as` to run

Comment: I have a good grasp of what's going on here.  How could I employ this method when my joins DO produce duplicates?

Comment: Use count distinct, as suggested in the solution.

Comment: i tried that and a typo made it not work.  so much for my diligence.  this is a neat, easy solution.  far easier than what i had.  thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate way:

```
select      RRTGotAlert         = case RRTGotAlert when 0 then 'N' when 1 then 'Y' end
            ,TZ_OnPilotUnit_N   = sum(TZ_OnPilotUnit_N)
            ,TZ_OnPilotUnit_Y   = sum(TZ_OnPilotUnit_Y)
from        (select     RRTGotAlert
                        ,TZ_OnPilotUnit_N = [0]
                        ,TZ_OnPilotUnit_Y = [1]
            from        #analysis
            pivot       (count(Encounter) for TZ_OnPilotUnit in ([0],[1])) pvt) got_alert
group by    case RRTGotAlert when 0 then 'N' when 1 then 'Y' end
order by    case RRTGotAlert when 0 then 'N' when 1 then 'Y' end
```