# 2x2 contingency table constructing in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, contingency

I'm trying to construct a 2x2 contigency table as explained in the following link below:

[Ad hoc 2x2 contingency tables SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148653/ad-hoc-2x2-contingency-tables-sql-server-2008)
(tried to understand the code but couldn't wrap my head around it)

A loop is made to construct pairs as in C1,C1 C1,C2 C2,C1 C2,C2. (cartesian product)

These pairs are given as argument into the sql code. For this example I already have given the sql code a pair --> C1,C1

When constructing it for different pairs they are correct as in C1,C2 C2,C1 (after some modifications explained below). When making pairs of C1,C1 or C2,C2 it constructs a wrong contingency table.

For example (table name is alpha_occurence):

```
id   concept_uri   document_uri

1       C1      D1

2       C2      D1
```

2x2 Contingency table of the pairs C1,C1 should give from the given table above:

```
       C1     not C1
    C1  1     0
not C1  0     -
```

But instead gives (after some modifications):

```
       C1    not C1
    C1  0    1
not C1  1    -
```

note I have put a - for the value not C1, Not C1. Because to calculate that an other method is used.

This sql code is used to retrieve the values :

```
SELECT count(*) AS total FROM  
(SELECT document_uri,count(DISTINCT concept_uri) AS count_conc FROM mydb.alpha_occurence 
WHERE concept_uri IN ('C1','C1') 
GROUP BY document_uri 
HAVING count_conc >=2 ) 
AS amount_of_concept_co_occurence #value of both X and Y

UNION ALL 

SELECT count(*) AS total FROM 
(SELECT concept_uri,document_uri FROM mydb.alpha_occurence
WHERE concept_uri IN ('C1'))
AS only_concept_A #value of Only X not Y

UNION ALL 

SELECT count(*) AS total FROM
(SELECT concept_uri,document_uri FROM mydb.alpha_occurence 
WHERE concept_uri IN ('C1'))
AS only_concept_B #value of Not X only Y
```

After the values are retrieved a little script is run over these values to correct them. 
The following is done:

```
To get Only X and not Y            = only_concept_A - amount_of_concept_co_occurence 
To get Not X and Only Y            = Only_concept_B - amount_of_concept_co_occurence
To get the value of neither X or Y = total # of documents (which is not given here as the sample data only has data of which concept occurce in which document) - (amount_of_concept_co_occurence + Only X and not Y + Not X and Only Y)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and who samples of data.  You have non-sensical constructs like `not in ('c1', 'c1')` and mention "A" and "B", but have no such references in the query.

Comment: I have edited my question and hope i made it somewhat more understandable

Comment: Your question would be much clearer if you just showed some sample data and the results that you want.  I *know* what a contingency table is.  I *don't know* what your data looks like.  You might also consider closing this question and asking another one that better communicates what you are trying to accomplish with your data.

Answer (score 1):

I used this script

```
select concept_uri, document_uri, count(*) as count 
from table
group by concept_uri, document_uri
```

and they are ready..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.